# Cells that dynamically switch from fillable to displaying calculated value - ie: monthly cost <-> annual cost

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to create a sheet that allows users to enter costs either as monthly or as annual and have the other update.

As soon as they enter data in the monthly cell, I'd like the annual cell to have that value * 12.

As soon as they enter data in the annual cell, I'd like the monthly cell to have that value / 12.

I found an [example online of an Ohms Law Calculator](https://www.rhopointcomponents.com/help-services/engineering-calculators/ohms-law-calculator/) that has approximately the behavior I want.

Is this possible? I struggle to find search terms.

[image]

Comment: Your example is a form not a sheet.  You can do this by adding an entry column as well as a checkbox or drop menu to indictate if monthly or annual, or using Google Apps Script to code a solution.`onedit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a form that has a coded solution.  In sheets, you cannot edit a cell without overwriting the formula.  You will need to separate your calculations.  You can do this by

1. adding a value column with another column to indicate the frequency of the value;
2. add the frequencies as separate columns from the calculations;
3. code solution in Google Apps Script that detects edits to open of the values and automatically calculate the  other.

### Option 1:

```
# IN $D$3

=IF(B3<>"",
    IF(C3="Annual",B3,
       IF(C3="Monthly",B3*12,
          "Frequency!")),"-   ")

# IN $E$3

=IF(B3<>"",
    IF(C3="Annual",B3/12,
       IF(C3="Monthly",B3,
          "Frequency!")),"-   ")
```

**Cell $D$3**   (Option 1)
[image]

**Cell $E$3**   (Option 1)
[image]

**Cell $C$3**   (Option 1)
[image]

### Option 2:

```
# IN $D$3

=IF(B3<>"",IF(C3<>"","Error!",B3),
    IF(C3<>"",C3*12,"-   "))

# IN $E$3

=IF(B3<>"",
    IF(C3="Annual",B3/12,
       IF(C3="Monthly",B3,
          "Frequency!")),"-   ")
```

**Cell $D$3**   (Option 2)
[image]

**Cell $E$3**   (Option 2)
[image]

### Option 3:

Google [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/) that leverages the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Requires no formulas in the sheet:

1. script needs to be added to the spreadsheet:
   **Extensions** menu **> Apps Script**
2. Script will only update on explicit cell edits (not formulas)
3. Script is currently written to update a single cell (if you paste several values, only the first will be updated).
4. Script uses the **sheet name**, and **two named ranges** (one for **Annual** values and another for **Monthly** values).

By specifying the sheet name as well as the ranges, it is now possible to add content above, below, to either side of the affected ranges as well as on other sheets without having the script interfere.  For example, I added totals below the range in the example below and I do not want the script to replace my SUM formulas.

You can use whatever names you prefer, just be sure to update the script at the top in the ***customizations*** section with the actual names you use.

###### Names used in the example

| Name | Range | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| _annual | _calculate!B2:B9 | range with **Annual** values |
| _monthly | _calculate!C2:C9 | range with **Monthly** values |
| _calculate | _calculate | sheet name that contains the named ranges |

```
/* +-------------------------+
   | Start  (customizations) |   
   +-------------------------+  */

     var _annual  = "_annual"     // named range in your sheet
     var _monthly = "_monthly"    // named range in your sheet
     var _sheet   = "_calculate"  // your sheetname (tab) to check

/* +-------------------------+
   | End    (customizations) |   
   +-------------------------+  */

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var value = e.range.getValue();        // value in edited cell

  if ( typeof(value) == "number" &&      // confirm value is number
       _sheet == sheet.getName() ){      // confirm sheet name 
 
    var col = e.range.getColumnIndex();  // edited cell's column
    var row = e.range.getRowIndex();     // edited cell's row
    
    var yr = sheet.getRange(_annual).getColumnIndex();  
    var mn = sheet.getRange(_monthly).getColumnIndex();
    var rows = sheet.getRange(_annual).getA1Notation().split(":");
    var rowsbegin = rows[0].replace(/\D+/, '');
    var rowsend = rows[1].replace(/\D+/, '');
  
    if (( col == yr || col == mn ) && (           // confirm column is in range
          row >= rowsbegin && row <= rowsend )){  // confirm row is in  range

            ( col == yr ) ?
              sheet.getRange(row,mn).setValue(value/12) :
              sheet.getRange(row,yr).setValue(value*12);
    }

  }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I am going to use option 1 for now, but the scripts example is very useful. I really appreciate the time and effort you took to help me out.